# How do I add target="_blank" to a link within a specified div?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, external-links

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<div id="link_other">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a></li>
        <li>
            <div class="some_class">
                dsalkfnm sladkfm
                <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this case, the JavaScript would add `target="_blank"` to all links within the div `link_other`.

How can I do that using JavaScript?

Comment: Why not let the JavaScript detect which links are external?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
/* here are two different ways to do this */
//using jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');
});

// not using jquery
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementById('link_other').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
}
// jquery is prettier. :-)
```

You could also add a title tag to notify the user that you are doing this, to warn them, because as has been pointed out, it's not what users expect:

```
$('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank').attr('title','This link will open in a new window.');
```

Comment: He asked for javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: To be more precise, you can use for anchors: let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#sources + div a'); // Change selector

And use ES6 instead of for loop: anchors.forEach((elem) => { elem.setAttribute('target', '_blank') }

Comment: How can we do this in react.

Comment: Hello @AhmedShaikh please do add a new question here on Stack Overflow to ask that!

Answer (score 61):

Non-jquery:

```
// Very old browsers
// var linkList = document.getElementById('link_other').getElementsByTagName('a');

// New browsers (IE8+)
var linkList = document.querySelectorAll('#link_other a');

for(var i in linkList){
 linkList[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Instead of getAttributesByTagName, shouldn't it be getElementsByTagName?

Comment: Or just linkList[i].target = '_blank';

Comment: This version worked like a charm for me in wordpress when adding: target="_blank" to an RSS feed with elementor

Answer (score 8):

Bear in mind that doing this is considered bad practice in general by web developers and usability experts. Jakob Nielson has this to say about removing control of the users browsing experience:

> Avoid spawning multiple browser windows if at all possible — taking the "Back" button away from users can make their experience so painful that it usually far outweighs whatever benefit you're trying to provide. One common theory in favor of spawning the second window is that it keeps users from leaving your site, but ironically it may have just the opposite effect by preventing them from returning when they want to.

I believe this is the rationale for the target attribute being removed by the W3C from the XHTML 1.1 spec.

If you're dead set on taking this approach, Pim Jager's solution is good.

A nicer, more user friendly idea, would be to append a graphic to all of your external links, indicating to the user that following the link will take them externally.

You could do this with jquery:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function() {
    $('<img width="10px" height="10px" src="/images/skin/external.png" alt="External Link" />').appendTo(this)

});
```

Comment: While I mostly agree with what you're saying, I think target blank and the "rel='external'" trick do have their place, especially when you're linking to a PDF.

Comment: rel="external" is interesting -- http://www.sitepoint.com/article/standards-compliant-world/3/ -- though it looks like it needs to be used in conjunction with JavaScript to get it to work. It does allow you to avoid using the disallowed xhtml attribute "target" in-line in your html though.

Thanks for mentioning it though, Mike. rel="external" is worth following. :-)

Comment: Jimmy, what would your reasoning be for doing that when you can use a relative path?

Comment: Reading J.Nielson's name here reminds me of http://bokardo.com/archives/comic-jakob-who/ ;-)

Comment: I know this was posted quite a while ago, but I see the same issue happen all too often today. Someone prefaces their answer with a rant about the detrimental aspects of using the requested information, but then fails to answer the specific question that was asked. jQuery is not the same as JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery:

```
 $('#link_other a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('target', '_BLANK');
 });
```

Comment: Can't you just do: $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');  ?

Comment: shorter is:
 $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');
as artlung posted

Answer (score 3):

I use this for every external link:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    if (anchors[i].hostname != window.location.hostname) {
        anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, even with ```a``` links that have a specified class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inline:

```
$('#link_other').find('a').attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for every external link

```
$('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"]').attr('target', '_blank');
```