# How to force external URLs inserted in the wagtail Draftail editor to open on the new tab?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail, richtext

Basically I need that the `target="_blank"` attribute would be added to all the external URLs inserted in the `wagtail` *Draftail* `richtext` editor:

[image: external url]

```
In [2]: wagtail.__version__
Out[2]: '2.0.1'
```

---

*EDIT-1*: ***This is not a duplicate***. `wagtail` version 2 uses completely different `richtext` editor.

The proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270862/2146346) suggests `$('a[href^="http://"]').attr('target', '_blank')` which would add the appropriate attribute to the **all links on the page** which contain `http://`. It's very suboptimal solution, as there may be many more links on the page which do not require such a treatment. Obviously there must be more adequate fix, especially because `wagtail` already differentiate `Internal` and `External` links on the editor UI (see attached image).

*EDIT-2*:

It seems that in the `wagtail.core.rich_text.feature_registry.FeatureRegistry` class there is a method, which to my best understanding assign different handler to the different URL type, however I don't see what these these handlers are, how they get called or how to modify them?

```
def register_link_type(self, link_type, handler):
    self.link_types[link_type] = handler
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making external links open in a new window in wagtail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300941/making-external-links-open-in-a-new-window-in-wagtail)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as wagtail version 2 uses completely different richtext editor.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the answer there? The solution is completely independent of the back-end editor.

Comment: This is a duplicate. The rich text editors have changed, but the link chooser hasn't, and server-side processing is also mostly the same.

Comment: @ThibaudColas As I explained in the Edit-1, the proposed answer is nothing more but a `JavaScript` **hack**. You can mask dozens of framework problems by throwing at them tons of JavaScript, but it will not solve core problems. You've mentioned that the `server-side processing is also mostly the same` (hence you agree it's different, but kind of similar), so I assume you know a lot about `wagtail` internals? Why not then post a proper answer? This problem has to be solved in the guts of the framework (`wagtail`) and not be masked by the `JavaScript`.

Comment: @NarūnasK It's one thing for you not to like the currently proposed solution, but it doesn't make your question less of a duplicate. Duplicates make it harder for people to find correct answers. And yes, I'm going to propose a better solution, (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3257#issuecomment-473674142), but I'll be responding on that other question only.

Comment: @ThibaudColas Very well, post it wherever you like, as long as you will provide the correct solution. Just note, that your answer will probably hang around as a comment next to the accepted incorrect answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create file wagtail_hooks.py and add the following lines:

```
class NewWindowExternalLinkHandler(LinkHandler):
    identifier = 'external'

    @classmethod
    def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
        href = attrs["href"]
        return '<a href="%s" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">' % escape(href)

@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_rich_text_handlers(features):
    features.register_link_type(NewWindowExternalLinkHandler)
```