# Best way to add target ='_blank' for href in a string using UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I've got data in sql server 2012 that contains text with links `<a href="test/test">test </a>` with out target i need to add target for the string data. I need to create a User defined function for that. Does any one have any sample code for this.

Example text -

`If you've ever thought one of your text message threads was so good it deserved to be published, you may be on to something.view.  <a href="/apple/sdffsd/sdffs">njkhj </a> In future iterations, users will be able to post .<br><br>You may update your email address at any time by going to <a href="/apple/fafasdf/sdfsdf">sdffsd</a>. Our whole goal is to have the reader go through an entire narrative arc in five minutes and consume it in a way that's native to mobile," says Gupta go to <a href="/a/s/sdfsf"> sdfsdf  </a>  which is one of my favorite books, is told as letters back and forth between the two main`

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not work?  SO is not a place where you ask for a tailored solution while showing zero effort on your part.

Comment: please elaborate on target `i need to add target`

Comment: As the `target='_blank'` is useless outside a browser, could you not manage that in your application ? Something like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901679/jquery-add-target-blank-for-outgoing-link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple replace would do the trick

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Some large text with a <a href="test/test">link</a> to content'

Select Replace(@String,' href=','_target="blank" href=')
```

Returns

```
(No column name)
Some large text with a <a _target="blank" href="test/test">link</a> to content
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought the same... I realized that i was over complicating things and just needed to think simple.

Comment: @akki  Always too easy to over think things

Comment: Did not use stack over flow a lot , where can i mark it as answered?

Comment: @akki near the Up/Down Vote

Answer (score 0):

We can also use 
`SELECT REPLACE(text,'<a','<a target="_blank" ');
Go`