# jQuery adding target _blank not opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

In reference to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901679/jquery-add-target-blank-for-outgoing-link), I'm trying to make my site work such that any external link opens in a new tab.

The jQuery for each of the answers on the aforementioned question works (meaning I see `target="_blank"` being added to external links when I use Chrome or Safari's inspector, but clicking on the links themselves do not open in a new tab or new window.

Have modern browsers changed such that this functionality no longer works? Or am I missing something else?

**Update:** Per @hakam-fostok's request, here is the relevant code:

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').attr('target', function() {
    if(this.host == location.host) return '_self'
    else return '_blank'
  });
});
```

Link (as seen in Chrome inspector):

```
<a href="http://espn.com" target="_blank">ESPN</a>
```

**Update 2:** I'm not sure this matters, but the app is Rails 4.2.7.1, running jQuery 2.2.4.

Comment: can you please provide the full version of the 'anchor's html element? this should work without problems

Comment: Please try setting the `target` using `prop` instead of `attr`. Attributes are ment as the *initial* value of the corresponding HTML element instance.

Answer (score 2):

Usually if you want to modify run-time properties of an existing HTML element, you have to use the `prop` function instead of `attr`. See the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

The difference in simple words is that `prop` sets the corresponding property of the HTML element, whereas `attr` sets *only* the attribute value. Attribute values are ment to be initial values of run-time properties.

```
$(function() {
  $('a').prop('target', function() {
    if(this.host == location.host) return '_self'
    else return '_blank'
  });
});
```

Comment: Just tried this - it did not work. Still simply opened the same window in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Then please try to create a jsfiddle which reproduces your issue, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Also note that there might be cases when the browsers override this setting in result of some local settings or circumstances. So to test it, try to create two static links (without `jQuery`) so you can see if it works at all.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b8s4bLhm/1/ - and of course, the jsfiddle works. I'm wondering if it's Rails preventing this somehow?

Comment: I assume you mean create a "hard-coded" `target="_blank"` link in my app. When I do this, yes, it works as expected.

Comment: Yes I ment that. It sounds really interesting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137816/discussion-between-zoltan-tamasi-and-cdub).