# JavaScript: How do I add an attribute?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the target attribute to some anchors when a radio button is checked; however it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<ul id="main">
    <li><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="radio" name="input" id="input" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('input').checked = function changeTarget() {
    document.anchors.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
</script>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? (Note: I don't want a JQuery solution)

Thanks.

Edit: Phew. Done it thanks to all the answers, here's my final code:

```
    document.getElementById('input').onclick = function changeTarget() {
    if(this.checked) {
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
            b[a].target = '_blank';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804256/how-do-i-add-target-blank-to-a-link-within-a-specified-div you may check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your edited code you set the targets every time to `_blank` when clicking the radio button. Also `anchors`-collection is not the right-one to use in this case.

```
document.getElementById('input').onclick = function changeTarget() {
    var n,a=document.links.length;
    if(document.getElementById('input').checked){
        for(n=0;n<a;n++){
            document.links[n].target='_blank';
        }   
    }
}
```

`document.links` is a collection-object containing the `A`-elements in the document which have an `href` or `nohref`-attribute. A collection-object is quite similar to an array, and you can refer to it's members with an index (`n`).

Comment: I'm not confident with JavaScript so can you explain `links[n]` that to me? As in what does the [n] mean? Thanks.

Comment: @Teemu Why are you advocating `document.getElementById("input").value` over `this.value`?

Comment: what about the original question referring to `links[n]` what is the `[n]` for?

Comment: @Dennis Funny, seems that you're right with this... Never too old to learn... Thanks for a feedback.

Comment: @Harry Like I said in my answer, collection-objects are quite similar to arrays. `links[N]` refers to the `N`th member (actually a property) in the `links`-collection.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the "checked" property of the radio button to a function. The "checked" property is a **boolean** that indicates whether the radio button is currently checked. Thus, that statement has the effect of setting it to `true`. You probably intend to have that be an event handler, so that should probably be "onclick" instead of "checked".

Setting the "target" property of the `<a>` tags cannot be accomplished like that. You'll have to use `document.getElementsByTagName()` and then iterate through the node list that's returned, setting the "target" property of each. No need to use `.setAttribute()`; just set the property directly on the DOM nodes.

Comment: No, don't use `document.anchors`.  Use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`.

Comment: Okay thanks, can you look at my revised edit and see whats still wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`document.anchors` is a collection so you need to iterate over it.  You also want the `onclick` event - there you can determine if the input is checked or not.

```
document.getElementById('input').onclick = function changeTarget() {
    if( this.checked ) {
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i = anchors.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
            anchors[i].target = '_blank';
        }
    }
}
```

According to MDN - `document.anchors` only returns anchors with a name attribute - gEBTN will return all of the anchors.

Alternatively:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("click", changeTarget, false);
```

Comment: The "target" attribute from HTML is accessible as a property directly on the DOM nodes. No need to use `.setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, `checked` is a property so you cannot assign a function to it. 
You can attach a click event on `#input` to change anchors `target`:

```
document.getElementById('input').onclick = function()
{
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(this.checked)
        for(var i = 0, s = anchors.length; i < s; i++) {
          anchors[i].target = '_blank';
        }
    else
        for(var i = 0, s = anchors.length; i < s; i++) {
          anchors[i].target = '_self';
        }
}
```

UPDATE: In my code #input must a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="input" />
```