# HTML Add attribute on an element

Tags: javascript, html

When I was writing (a lot of) `<a>` tags I didn't write `'target="_blank"'`, so none of the links are leading to another windows or tag.

Is there a way to add `"target='_blank'"` to all the links with JavaScript?

Comment: beside the point, but wouldn't it make more sense to just modify the markup?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a search&replace?

Comment: Yeah, in my website has a lot of links, which is very difficult to type it in all the links.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need JavaScript at all. You can use the `base` element in your `head` to specify a base URL or target for anchors.

`<base target="_blank">` will make all links on your page open in new windows and/or tabs.

More information on the base element can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked. It's because I can't study on a paid place, so what is free I am studying, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered here: [How do I add target="_blank" to a link within a specified div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804256/how-do-i-add-target-blank-to-a-link-within-a-specified-div)

Code:

```
/* here are two different ways to do this */
//using jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');
});

// not using jquery
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementById('link_other').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
}
// jquery is prettier. :-)
```