# how to make the link in drupal open in new window which is redirected for "Link this field to the original piece of content"?

Tags: drupal

I have created the view which is having the fetched contents of title body etc..,title is connected with "Link this field to the original piece of content",
and i want that link should be opened in the new window,please help me on this,is there any way to make this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to do that with JavaScript. Something like explained here:

[How do I add target="_blank" to a link within a specified div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804256/how-do-i-add-target-blank-to-a-link-within-a-specified-div)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

And instead of that "#link_other a" you should put something for detecting your link(s) that you want to open in different page/tab.

Answer (score 0):

To Click title field choose Rewrite result option and put this html code and save the view.

[image]

[image]

```
<a href="node/[nid]" target="_blank">[title]<a/>
```