# How to open links in rich text field in new tab

Tags: xpages

I have an XPages app.  How can you open a link in a new tab, if the link is in a rich text field?

Source code:

```
<xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.Demo}" id="inputRichText3">
<xp:this.dojoAttributes>
<xp:dojoAttribute name="toolBarType" value="Slim">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
</xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you looked into using some client side JS code to add a target value of "_blank" to all <a> tags within divs with the 'xspInputFieldRichText' CSS class? Example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804256/how-do-i-add-target-blank-to-a-link-within-a-specified-div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could do it

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
dojo.forEach(dojo.query(".xspInputFieldRichText a"),function(aTag)
{dojo.attr(aTag,"target","_blank");
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added it to an onload event in xpage and it works.